# How do I listen to sample/preview in the iOS Music app?

Tags: ios, music

The iTunes desktop application has a feature where you can listen to a 90-second sample, or preview, of a song before purchasing it. However I can't find this feature on my iPhone. I'm looking in the "Music" app on iOS 9.2. Is there a different place that I should be looking? Is the feature hiding behind some sort of touch gesture that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be part of the iTunes app that comes bundled (pre-installed) on your iPhone.

Comment: Sorry, silly me -- I thought that there was no iTunes app on the iPhone, and that Music was basically it's replacement on the iPhone.

Comment: Is there a way to jump to the same song in the store when viewing a song that I don't own in the Music app? You'd think they'd have a way to do that...

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with some of that functionality as I usually do that on my computer but suspect the only shortcut would be to use Siri (which may not really be a shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

It was answered above perhaps, but the answer also applies to IPad. Do not open the Music App and hope to listen to music samples, like the old days. When you attempt to search for a song and try to play it in the Music app, you will get an annoying and repetitive "Join Apple Music" pop up panel, where you will be invited to get the 3 months free offer. Get out of Apple Music App completely.

First go to IOS Settings, scroll down to music and switch "Show Apple Music" to off. Then go to the **iTunes Store App** (not iTunes), and on the bottom, click the music icon, bottom, left side. Then you'll be able to do a search, click on the song/album title you want to hear, and listen to snippets, like the old, much better Apple Music set up. They over-paid $3 billion to Dre and Iovine for Beats Music and to recoup their investment, they try to push people into signing up. They don't have help info or docs in IOS/iMusic to clarify this misleading and confusing new protocol, which is purposeful.

Desktop Apple set up is different, but IOS/iMusic is now a sales funnel for Apple Music sign ups. That's why you'll have a difficult time trying to get info from Apple help pages or forums at Apple on simply how to play short samples. Sucks.

Answer (score 0):

As in iOS 11.2, you cannot view sample/preview song in Apple Music. You could however view them in iTunes store.

But it is cumbersome to switch to iTunes and search for the song you want to preview. There’s a way to fix this “automation”

First download workflow. Then add an extension to open the URL. Go to Apple Music. Choose one album and click show full album. Force touch a song you didn’t purchase. Choose share and select run workflow. Choose the extension you just create. It should open the album in iTunes store automatically.

Hope this helps